# Sintaxis erronea de MySql, en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy rescatado valores de mi Base de datos, y al hacer un var_dump a la variable $resultado me arroja el siguiente error.

> E:\wamp64\www\evasion\ajaxResume.php:18:boolean false

Podrían ayudarme a encontrar el error, les dejo la sintaxis de la query que escribí:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM medicion WHERE ppu = '".$ppu."' sentido = '".$sentido."'";
$resultados = mysqli_query($enlace, $query);
```

Comment: Te falta agregar `AND` u `OR` entre `ppu` y `sentido`, así por ejemplo: `"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM medicion WHERE ppu = '".$ppu."' AND sentido = '".$sentido."'"`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rápida respuesta!!! Lo corregí y funciono perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Encontré el error en la Sintaxis. Debió quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM medicion WHERE ppu = '".$ppu."' AND sentido = '".$sentido."'";
$resultados = mysqli_query($enlace, $query);
```